How to run GitHub Actions on a self-hosted runner with limited internet connectivity
I'm running a GitHub Actions workflow on a server with restricted internet connectivity. The firewall is configured to allow access only to the following domains required for essential operations (per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners):

github.com
api.github.com
*.actions.githubusercontent.com

The self-hosted runner starts successfully, but the workflow fails because it attempts to connect to codeload.github.com, which is blocked by the firewall.
I can manually download files from the internet to my laptop and upload them to the server, if needed.
Is there a way to preload actions (e.g., actions/checkout@v4) on the server so the workflow doesn't attempt to download them from codeload.github.com during execution?
If not, are there alternative solutions to make this setup work without changing the existing firewall rules?

If you need to download actions, you should permit the subdomains under "Needed for downloading actions".
